Clang-format putting in excessive tabs
I'm attempting to use clang-format (specifically the git clang-format integration) to format a commit of mine.
When doing so, in multiple locations the clang-format'd output has a ridiculous amount of tabs. I am sure that this is purely user-error, but I've tried myriad combinations of tab settings etc. and have not been able to avoid this result. I'm hoping this tool will help us consistently format our code. Here's an example.
Before git clang-format --style=FILE origin/main
                    std::pair<fdfsgrgrgrdhrhnftydydtydj, ragrttrthyjyehtt> greaghjryjnResult = tdshethhterhtethjyrtrtrjt::tesgsjjrt(SErggdskuhwrgbnespevil, efasiljnefilfd, gsrgsgrs, gsrgrgrgjsrtrerrfes, htrehetsesehh5thfgd, htreaserhhesc, hesthehesth, hsethhetshetshyyrseydh, ths);

After:
                    std::pair<fdfsgrgrgrdhrhnftydydtydj, ragrttrthyjyehtt> greaghjryjnResult =

                    tdshethhterhtethjyrtrtrjt::tesgsjjrt(SErggdskuhwrgbnespevil, efasiljnefilfd, gsrgsgrs, gsrgrgrgjsrtrerrfes,

                                                                                             htrehetsesehh5thfgd, htreaserhhesc, hesthehesth, hsethhetshetshyyrseydh,

                                                                                             ths);


Here's the whole of my .clang-format file:
---
Language:        Cpp
BasedOnStyle:  LLVM

BraceWrapping:
  AfterCaseLabel:  true
  AfterControlStatement: true
  BeforeElse:      true
BreakBeforeBraces: Custom

ColumnLimit:     120

SortIncludes:    false

ConstructorInitializerIndentWidth: 0
ContinuationIndentWidth:  0
IndentWidth:              2
TabWidth:                 2
UseTab:                   Always
...

I've tried all sorts of combinations of tabwidth, ContinuationIndentation, UseTab options, etc...

Holy moly. I think that what I've been banging my head against is mostly a product of the visuals produced by my difftool. That's embarrassing. I will check tomorrow.

Yup. The solution is, make sure that your formatter, your difftool, and your IDE are all on the same page about tab width before trying to troubleshoot such things. (If the formatter has a different definition of tab width, it will insert an incorrect number of tabs to line up with text).
It all makes sense and is very simple, but I got my head screwed on wrong and was chasing my tail for embarrassingly long.
In related news, I am now a spaces-only extremist.

In relation to keeping the question or deleting it, it is up to you. Keep it if you think other people might find the answer helpful, delete it otherwise. If you decide to keep it, you can tick/check this question to indicate to the platform that it is answered.
